# CSS Text Manipulation (Effect) inside FlexBox

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position

I am using CSS to display some text with an effect on a single page.

However i am now also trying to make it vertical align using flexbox but and struggling to understand how this would be done when the text effect is using absolute and relative positioning.

Current horizontal aligned text https://codepen.io/medoix/pen/WoyvMe

CSS

```
@import "compass/css3";

body{
  background:black;
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
}

.glitch{
  color:white;
  font-size:100px;
  position:relative;
  width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
@keyframes noise-anim{
  $steps:20;
  @for $i from 0 through $steps{
    #{percentage($i*(1/$steps))}{
      clip:rect(random(100)+px,9999px,random(100)+px,0);
    }
  }
}
.glitch:after{
  content:attr(data-text);
  position:absolute;
  left:2px;
  text-shadow:-1px 0 red;
  top:0;
  color:white;
  background:black;
  overflow:hidden;
  clip:rect(0,900px,0,0); 
  animation:noise-anim 2s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes noise-anim-2{
  $steps:20;
  @for $i from 0 through $steps{
    #{percentage($i*(1/$steps))}{
      clip:rect(random(100)+px,9999px,random(100)+px,0);
    }
  }
}
.glitch:before{
  content:attr(data-text);
  position:absolute;
  left:-2px;
  text-shadow:1px 0 blue; 
  top:0;
  color:white;
  background:black;
  overflow:hidden;
  clip:rect(0,900px,0,0); 
  animation:noise-anim-2 3s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}
```

HTML

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Varela' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="glitch" data-text="TEST">TEST</div>
```

Is it possible to vertically align inside flexbox while still getting the same effect?

Comment: Do you need to use flexbox for this, or could you use another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a small addition - not flexbox, but does the trick. Will center the text in it's closest relatively positioned parent (or, in this case, the body).

You can see a codepen demo [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObErJb).

```
<div class="glitch-wrapper">
    <div class="glitch" data-text="TEST">TEST</div>
</div>

.glitch-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with flex, the simpliest is display + margin and an height if needed:

```
body{
  display:flex;
  height:100vh;
}

.glitch{
  margin: auto;
}
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VmdqmL

Comment: This aligns it correctly but the effect seems to be affected and not correct.